# Can anyone help me how to write junit for this code

Tags: junit4

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xslt"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The first step in writing JUnit tests is knowing what you want to test. So that is the best place to start. First, look at your code and try to break down which are the moving pieces. Ask yourself "what could possibly break? what am I worried about not working?" For instance, you could test what happens if `transform.xslt` doesn't exist.

I think step one for you is to take all of the code you currently have in `main()` and move it into an object. You can start by making it an instance method on the class. That will give you a way to decouple the code you want to test from running `main`.

If you search online you will find many tutorials on JUnit, it will likely help you to work through a few of them.